# Using Selenium + Pandas to extract a table from multiple different pages

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, scrape

I have currently written a code using Selenium + Pandas to go to a website, login to that website (as some of the data is hidden behind the account login), then go to a specific page and extract the data table, and save that data table to an excel sheet.

The problem is that I need the data from 10-15 different pages, and all in one excel sheet.

This website states the upcoming dividends for companies, and I have a list of companies to check on a daily basis.

It would be straight forward to go to each page and save the table in an individual excel sheet for each page. However, I need to combine them all. How would you go about it?

For the below I've excluded the login details, and used Apple as an example company.

```
# Load selenium components
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd

# Establish chrome driver and go to report site URL
url = "https://www.dividendmax.com/login"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\PythonDrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

# Establish login credentials
username = driver.find_element_by_id("user_session_email")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("MY_EMAIL_LOGIN")

password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_session_password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("MY_PASSWORD")

# Instruct Selenium to complete login
driver.find_element_by_name("button").click()


#Define Portfolio & Links
URL = "https://www.dividendmax.com/united-states/nasdaq/technology-hardware-and-equipment/apple-inc/dividends"

#Instruct Selenium to go to Dividend Page
driver.get(URL)

#Instruct Selenium to obtain data from Table

page = driver.get(URL)
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
print(df.head())

# Write to Excel
df.to_excel('AppleScrape2.xlsx')
```

I'm quite new to Python I'm afraid, so apologies if the code is a little messy (been doing this for a few days only)

Comment: Try [DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) to combine your dataframes, e.g., `df = df.append(df2)`, `df = df.append(df3)`, ..., before calling `df.to_excel('AppleScrape2.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

Try [DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) to combine your dataframes, e.g.,

```py
df = df.append(df2)
df = df.append(df3)
#...
```

before calling `df.to_excel('AppleScrape2.xlsx')`.